# I have 3 functions I am trying to put into a Switch Case

Tags: jquery

Here are the functions:

```
function blockLayer1(){
    $('#block1').click(function() {
        $("#layer1").toggle();
    });
        }

function blockLayer2(){
$('#block2').click(function() {
    $("#layer2").toggle();
});
    }

function blockLayer3(){
$('#block3').click(function() {
    $("#layer3").toggle();
});
  }
```

Here is the case that is not working:

```
$("#block").click(function(evt) {

 switch ($("#layer_container").index(this)) {
    case 0 :
    $("#layer1").toggle();
    break;
    case 1 :
    $("#layer2").toggle();
    break;
    case 2 :
    $("#layer3").toggle();
    break;

   }
 });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need so many functions? What do the functions have in common with the switch? You have asked 7 questions and accepted NONE, why should we answer your question?

Comment: Sorry I needed to read the rules...I will get on that...thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try abstracting this a bit further and just create one function:

```
function blockLayer(layerNum) {
    $('#block' + layerNum).click(function() {
        $("#layer" + layerNum).toggle();
    });
}
```

You have the same elements of code repeating except 1 part (the number), so it makes for a good case to abstract & simplify.

Comment: Why pass the num, and not the element?

Comment: I need to see more of the markup to understand the structure of the elements and what specifically OP is trying to accomplish. At face value of what is in the question right now, this is how it could be abstracted.